# Validate only first two built objects title attribute of nested attributes rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I am building 4 objects of learning objectives for course which is accepting options as nested attributes. I want to only validate first two  title value presence of learning objectives while the 2 should be optional i.e reject if blank.

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :learning_objectives
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :learning_objectives
end

class LearningObjective < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :course
   validates_presence_of :title
end
```

How can I validate the first 2 built objects only?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific. Are all options instances of the same model? Could you post that model and it's attributes? And as @Зелёный said, you should always specify what you've tried.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Add a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods), such as:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :learning_objectives
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :learning_objectives

  MIN_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES = 2
  MAX_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES = 4

  validate :learning_objectives_count_in_range

  private

  def learning_objectives_count_in_range
    objectives_count = learning_objectives.count
    return if objectives_count.between?(MIN_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES, MAX_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES)

    errors.add(:base, "must have between #{MIN_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES} and #{MAX_LEARNING_OBJECTIVES} learning objectives")
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually want to validate presence of title of learning objective not whole object. It should only validate title of first two learning objectives and reject if the rest of the title are blank.

Comment: I don't understand. "Validate the first two ... Rest if the rest are blank." Do you mean only the first two objectives need a title?

Comment: `titled_objectives_count  = learning_objectives.where.not(title: [nil, '']).count` and `untitled_objectives_count  = learning_objectives.where(title: [nil, '']).count`. It should be fairly easy to modify my method above with whatever logic you're trying to describe, no?

Comment: Although of course, if the title is actually **optional** for some learning objectives, then you should *not* be doing `validates_presence_of :title` on the `LearningObjective`.